# Javascript async skips if-else

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have an if-else block that parses user input before making a http.get() to the server. However, the if-else keeps on being skipped over. I tried rearranging my code to force it to complete the if-else before calling get(), but nothing seems to work. I'm also using AngularJS.

```
//controller
function search($scope, $http, $location) 
{
    function parse(item)
    {
      if(item.match(/str1/g))
      {
        item = item.replace(/str1/g, 'one');
      }

      else if(item.match(/str2/g))
      {
        item = item.replace(/str2/g, 'two');
      }

      else if(item.match(/str3/g))
      {
        item = item.replace(/str3/g, 'three');
      }

      //ad infinitum
      return item;
    }

    $http.get('/search='+ parse($location.search().query.toLowerCase()))
         .success(function(data) {
            $scope.count = data.length;
            $scope.items = data;
            $scope.exists = data.length > 0;
         })
         .error(function(err) {

         });
}
```

Comment: I think you need to learn about [`return` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning `item` in your `parse()` function. Your `parse()` function is being treated as a string but there's no return value.

At the end of your function there should be a return, like so:

```
function parse(item)
{
  if(item.match(/str1/g))
  {
    item = item.replace(/str1/g, 'one');
  }

  else if(item.match(/str2/g))
  {
    item = item.replace(/str2/g, 'two');
  }

  else if(item.match(/str3/g))
  {
    item = item.replace(/str3/g, 'three');
  }

  //ad infinitum

  return item;

}
```

Read up on `return` Statements here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp

Another way to accomplish what you're trying to do is simply not creating a local `parse()` function and just doing the string handling directly in the `search()` scope:

```
function search($scope, $http, $location) 
{
      var item = $location.search().query.toLowerCase();

      if(item.match(/str1/g))
      {
        item = item.replace(/str1/g, 'one');
      }

      else if(item.match(/str2/g))
      {
        item = item.replace(/str2/g, 'two');
      }

      else if(item.match(/str3/g))
      {
        item = item.replace(/str3/g, 'three');
      }

      //ad infinitum

    $http.get('/search='+ item)
         .success(function(data) {
            $scope.count = data.length;
            $scope.items = data;
            $scope.exists = data.length > 0;
         })
         .error(function(err) {

         });
}
```